# bcrypt && bcryptjs compare password always return false in my case

Tags: postgresql, passwords, compare, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I have a user model(sequelize for Postgres) have below comparePassword function:
[image: User model function for comparePassword]

In login controller, I am checking password to let user login as below:
[image: Checking password in controller]

But any user fail to login because of comparePassword always return "false". I created several new users successfully and then when try to login, it gave the same "false" compare results.

I had tried the two module (bcrypt and bcryptjs), while same results.

Checked the stackoverflow, and found similar issue by post title, while not the same.

I tried the compareSync, it also gave false compare result.

My question: The hash calculation should be the same when creating the password hash to store in the database and the later comparing Password. where is the pit? what's the mistakes in my User model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In similar situation I had placed the lowercase validation on **password** in the **User Model**. That was giving me always bcrypt compare false. When removing it everything ran as usual.